# How to find newly added,deleted and modified files in git repository using Git Api in Java

Tags: git, github, egit, jgit

Using Git Api in Java(Egit and Jgit Api),I want to trace out newly added,deleted and modified files in Git repository.How can I do this??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any attempt to search the answer with a tool such as [Excite](http://google.com) or [AltaVista](http://bing.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at **[JGit unit tests](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api)** for finding a lot of examples.

That includes [`org.eclipse.jgit.api.StatusCommandTest`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Status.java)

```java
Git git = new Git(db);
writeTrashFile("a", "content of a");
writeTrashFile("b", "content of b");
writeTrashFile("c", "content of c");

git.add().addFilepattern("a").addFilepattern("b").call();

Status stat = git.status().call();   // git status right there

assertEquals(set("a", "b"), stat.getAdded());
```